# Getting the comma out of YEAR function in salesforce formula builder?

Tags: formula, operators

**I have a YEAR(CloseDate) which required to be a number field type.
And when I try to convert it to text to get rid of the 2,014 comma with something like this...**
TEXT(YEAR(CloseDate))
**or this...**
YEAR(TEXT(CloseDate))

**It states...**

*Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number). (Related field: Formula)*

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if understand, you created a formula field of type number to get the year of a Date field ?
I think you have to change the type of the formula to text and use your first one

```
 TEXT(YEAR(CloseDate))
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Melmoussaoui, that did it. I should have tested the text but overlooked, I guess I was to close to it.